# AJAX with promise

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, ecmascript-6, promise

How to use promises (ES6) and .then method in order to this code will work?

```
getGif: function (searchingText, callback) {
        var url = GIPHY_API_URL + '/v1/gifs/random?api_key=' + GIPHY_PUB_KEY + '&tag=' + searchingText;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).data;
                var gif = {
                    url: data.fixed_width_downsampled_url,
                    sourceUrl: data.url
                };
                callback(gif);
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    },
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises)

Comment: @George can you show me how it works on my code?

Answer (score 0):

Using Promise-Based XHR your code looks like:

```
getGif = function (searchingText) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{

        var url = GIPHY_API_URL + '/v1/gifs/random?api_key=' + GIPHY_PUB_KEY + '&tag=' + searchingText;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // Setup our listener to process compeleted requests
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

            // Only run if the request is complete
            if (xhr.readyState !== 4) return;

            // Process the response
            if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
                // If successful
                var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).data;
                var gif = {
                    url: data.fixed_width_downsampled_url,
                    sourceUrl: data.url
                };
                resolve(gif);
            } else {
                // If failed
                reject({
                    status: request.status,
                    statusText: request.statusText
                });
            }

        };
        xhr.open('GET', url);
        xhr.send();
  });

}
```

Need to invoke method depends on signature of function.

```
getGif(searchText).then((response)=>{
   console.log(response);
}, (error)=> { 
  console.log(error);
})
```